# Why this code doesn't seem to run?

Tags: jquery

I was writing a jquery script to change the color of the parent div whenever the keydown event is triggered for the child-input element, but the code doesn't seem to run.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("input").keydown(function(){
                        $("#div").css("background-color","teal");
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="div">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps the background is completely filled?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/gu94r/

Comment: try this `$("#div").css({ 'background-color': 'teal' });`

Comment: @War10ck please correct your code. It should be a comma instead of colon.

Comment: @SumitGera it shouldn't. This is an object literal. Note the added curly brackets.

Comment: No, it's an object, not a function call. comma would actually be an error.

Comment: @Femaref note the former is equivalent to the suggested replacement

Comment: @Jan Dvorak but why does it works in my case?

Comment: @SumitGera there is no problem with your way of setting the CSS. You may still want to use the object literal method, though. It lets you set multiple properties at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot 'http' in your jquery link (assuming you are using `file://` to access the file), change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

When ready to go to a server change it back to say `//ajax.googleapis.com/...` to avoid http/https issue that @Femaref mentioned

Comment: He hasn't, it's that way so the appropiate url-scheme (`http` or `https`) is chosen automatically and you don't introduce a security hole. See [google hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#Libraries)

Comment: @SumitGera where are you testing? Perhaps your browser (I'm guessing it's IE) doesn't understand `//...`

Comment: if he's working on a local file and referencing `file:///C:/` then he needs `http`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I am using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: i tried with both- the local file and one hosted on google server. it works after using http protocol.

Comment: yes but how are you accessing the file when working locally, what does the address bar say?

Comment: +1 to this answer, but it does need some reformulation to mention the `file://` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all of your code then the div doesn't have any room around it to show the background.

Please see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RcyQW/

If you add `padding:5px;` the div does then show the background colour.

Also note it will only be triggered when a user types something into the input, not when it has focus.

Comment: @JanDvorak:yes you're right it does :)  but I wasn't sure if this was the complete source or just a test, so I added the padding just to make sure it was visible.